# Retrieve data from database as utf-8 in ZF2

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, zend-framework2

I'm trying to make sure the data received from my database is in utf-8, using Zend Frameword 2.
To do so, I encoded my php files in utf-8 and I set the meta charset to utf-8 (to make sure what shows on the page is in utf-8).

I also tried to set my adapter's charset to utf-8 but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the data.
I tried many ways:

```
$adapter = new Adapter(array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'database' => $database,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'charset' => 'utf8'
));

$adapter = new Adapter(array(
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'database' => $database,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'charset' => 'utf-8'
    ));

$adapter = new Adapter(array(
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'database' => $database,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'driverOptions' => array(
                    1002=>'SET NAMES utf8'
            )
    ));
```

I fetch the data using a TableGateway object. Should I specify in that object that it is in utf-8? (but I didn't see a property to do so in that object)

Here is how I fetch the data:

```
$results = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
if(count($results) > 0){
    //this loop transforms each object into an audio
    foreach($results as $row){
        $data['object'][$row->id] = $row;
    }
}
```

I pass the data in my Controller using:

```
$view->setVariable('arAudios', $arAudios);
```

I then print the data in the view using a print_r:

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($arAudios); echo '</pre>';?>
```

The data written directly on the page as well as other variables passed from the controller to the page are encoded correctly, but the data retrieved from the database shows ? where special characters should be. 
  They show correctly if I use utf8_encode(), so I assume the data was not encoded when fetched from the database.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: is your database storing the data in utf8? run mysql> show table status; and see what the collation column says

Comment: I've set the collation to utf8_general_ci for all my tables.

Answer (score 1):

Just do your global configure like

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=singclub;host=localhost;',
        'username'       => 'root',
        'password'       => '',
        'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"
        ),
    ),
);
```